# Why is the Track to constraint "legacy"?

Tags: constraints

The tooltip for the "Track to" constraint says: "Legacy tracking constraint prone to twisting artifacts".

Why is it "legacy"? Has it been replaced with something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some further research, I found that [Joshua Leung](https://developer.blender.org/p/aligorith/) added this text to source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_constraint.c when he [committed](https://developer.blender.org/rBACae3cf92491be73f353b278f1632a68990d0e44d9) the new Damped track constraint, indicating that Track to has been superseded by Locked track and Damped track.

Of course I don't think anyone's about to deprecate Track to.

Comment: Yeah this should be removed.. after 6 years, locked track does a totally different thing - I was concerned I wasn't using best practices. Thanks @foobarbecue