# Constraint the camera to look at an object

Tags: camera, constraints

In my scene I have a camera sitting at the origin. I would like to contraint it so that it always looks at the center of a given object. But the camera should not change its position.

I found some answers using a "TrackTo" or "LockedTrack" constraint but could not manage to make it work.

Could I probably use a Driver for this and if yes, how can I adjust it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Set the camera with a **[Track To](http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html)** constraint.

- Select the "Target" object.
- In the "To" section select -Z and in the "Up" section set it to *Y*
- Use *World Space*

[image]

[image]

[image]

The camera will then point at the target object's origin.

To understand those settings you have to think of the LOCAL AXES for the camera: X is Horizontal, Y vertical and Z is depth. Negative Z is what is in front of the camera.

[image]

To maintain the object's Z axis aligned at all times enable Target Z.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You saved my Day! I just could not figure out the right setup!

Comment: The "Track to" link is broken.

Comment: Track To is marked legacy, about replacement see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27037/why-is-the-track-to-constraint-legacy