# Maneuvering Camera along Path

Tags: camera, path

I am trying to make the camera in Blender follow a direct path. I want it to rotate around a piece of text. I'm not really sure how to describe it, so bear with me:

My text is in the center of the grid, where the blue, red, and green bars meet. I have placed the start of the path up above the text a few units, and far over to the left of it. I wish I could give you exact coordinates, but Blender doesn't always seem to read the same values for whatever reason (x=0, y=0, and z=0 doesn't always show up at the center of the grid). I have the path curving gradually down and on a curve, ending so that the camera is aimed directly at the text, a full front on view. The problem is, I can't get the camera to stay consistently aimed at the text. It either ends askew (which I thought I could remedy by changing the rotation values to 0, but somehow, that made it even less level!) or it cuts out part of the text on its journey. Can anyone give me a hand with this? Thank you in advance!

Ethan

Comment: Explore adding a "Track To" constraint to the camera. Maybe add an Empty to the center of the text and Track To the Empty.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object/42839#42839 --and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46888/camera-follow-path-and-change-rotation/46898#46898