# My camera will not follow the object it is constrained to

Tags: camera, path

I have a camera here that is constrained to look at an empty object. It is also following along a path. I have follow unchecked on the path but when the camera reaches a turn it flips on its side regardless if i'm using follow or not. I locked the Y rotation of it which didn't help one bit. Does anyone have any ideas what to do about this?

[image]

[image]
When it takes a shit ^^^^^

Comment: Related link:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object/42839#42839

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just rotated the camera and it somehow reset correctly enough to even remove the limit rotation modifier. This was definitely a bug, I didn't even keyframe the rotation to fix it... If you are having this problem try rotating the camera on the appropriate axis and it will reset the rotation of the curve. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the empty the parent of the camera? Then any position or rotation change will affect the camera. Seems to work best for me

Comment: when I do that the camera doesn't follow the curve anymore. I might use that for the following scene though, thanks.