# Messed up camera orientations with Follow Path and Track To constraints

Tags: animation, camera, constraints

I’m having trouble setting up camera animations using the following setup:

I’ve set an empty to follow a path, and a child empty to aim at target empties. Like this:

**Empty.Cam.Following**

Follow Path: Forward X, Up Z, Follow Curve

**Empty.Cam.Tracking**

Child Of (Empty.Cam.Following), Track To (Empty.Aim.001): To X, Up Z

**Camera**

Child Of (Empty.Cam.Tracking)

[image]

**Issue 1**: Even though the path is pointing straight towards the X-axis Empty.Cam.Following won’t orient itself properly so I had to rotate/align it manually.

**Issue 2**: Once oriented manually it follows the curve’s direction but as soon as I set the Track To constraint on the child empty the camera points in all of the wrong directions and there appears to be no way to get it to point to the target.

So I can either have it follow the curve’s orientation or aim at targets, but not move between those orientations by keyframing the influence value on the Track To constraint.
I’ve already tried every combination of To/Up on both constraints.

Is this setup correct at all or did I mess it up at some point?

Comment: Negative Z is what is "in front" of the camera. Maybe this link can help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object/42839#42839

Comment: or this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object/42839#42839